# Redirect project url to custom domain

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pages

I publish my project to GitLab Pages and add my custom domain. Now I want to redirect the default GitLab url `username.gitlab.io/project` to my domain name `mydomain.com`. I add two records in DNS as below:

```
www.mydomain.com  CNAME  mydomian.com
www.mydomain.com  CNAME  username.gitlab.io/project
```

but it dosen’t work. How should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at an url, for example: `http://example.net/foo/bar` the domain name is **only** the `example.net` part.

DNS only controls domain names, so you will not be able to use CNAME records to point to subdirectories on the target domain.

To do something like that, you would need a webserver which proxies requests to that directory. (Search for nginx reverse-proxy for some examples)